# Primefaces datatable pass data to backing bean

Tags: session, primefaces, datatable

We are using primefaces 5.There is a datatable with one output text column and one with text field. We want to pass data from datatable to backing bean. If the scope of bean is request then the value of datatable does not gets passed to the backing bean. If the scope of bean is session then the value of datatable gets passed to the backing bean. But if we keep the scope of bean as session then values on the form get retained when we come back to the same page.

Given below is our code

```
    <h:form id="createForm" prependId="false">
    <p:messages id="errorMsgs"></p:messages>
    <p:panelGrid columns="1">
    <p:accordionPanel style="align:top;margin" prependId="false">
    <p:tab title="MainTab">
    <p:panelGrid columns="4" cellpadding="5">                                           
    <p:outputLabel for="id" value="Expense Items List: "/>
    <p:selectOneMenu id="id" style="width:250px" value="#{managedBean.expenseDetails.id}" required="true" requiredMessage="ExpenseDetails are required" filter="true" filterMatchMode="startsWith" >
    <p:ajax event="change" process="@this" listener="#{managedBean.getTEIList}" update="aTEModelList"/>
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select" itemValue="" noSelectionOption="true" />
    <f:selectItems value="#{managedBean.expenseDetailsModelList}" var="expenseDetails" itemLabel="#{expenseDetails.loadexpenseDetailsList}" itemValue="#{expenseDetails.id}" />
    </p:selectOneMenu>      
    <p:dataTable id="aTEModelList" var="aTEModelList" 
    value="#{managedBean.aTEModelList}" rowKey="#{expenseDetailsSearchResult.id}" >
    <p:column width="20%" >
    <f:facet name="header">
    <h:outputText value="Expense Short Description" />
    </f:facet>
    <h:outputText id="expenseShortDesc" value="#{aTEModelList.expenseShortDescription}" />
    </p:column>
    <p:column width="20%" >
    <f:facet name="header">
    <h:outputText value="Actual Expense Value" />
    </f:facet>
    <h:inputText id="actualexpenseDetailsExpense" value="#{aTEModelList.actualExpense}" />
    </p:column>
    </p:dataTable>
    </p:panelGrid>
    </p:tab>
    </p:accordionPanel>
    </p:panelGrid>
    <f:facet name="footer">
    <p:panelGrid columns="5">
    <p:commandButton id="submitButton" action="#{managedBean.addExpenseDetails}" value="Submit" ajax="false"  onclick="return validateForm();"></p:commandButton>
    </p:panelGrid>
    </f:facet>
    </h:form>
```